# Can I teach compiler that I'm not hiding a virtual function?

Tags: c++, gcc

[Here's](https://godbolt.org/z/oh1anhr6M) my code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    Base()  {
    }
    
    virtual void test();
};

struct Derived : Base {
    Derived() {
    }

    void test(int asd) {

    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived derived;
    derived.test(2);
}
```

But it says *warning: 'virtual void Base::test()' was hidden [-Woverloaded-virtual]*.
Since I do know that I'm doing stuff "correctly", how can I tell compiler that the called function is the overloaded one, correctly?

Comment: Try `derived.test();` (ie make an attempt to call the test in base) and you will see why the warning is needed.

Comment: @RichardCritten of course. I just need to suppress the warning. Is there any implicit way?

Comment: @273k None of the “duplicates” answer OP’s question, as far as I can see (at most there’s `pragma warning disable`, which isn’t really a solution). Note that OP does *not* want to override the method, nor do they (apparently) want to overload it. One could argue that the result is incredibly poor code design (and I’d agree!) but that alone isn’t grounds for considering this question a duplicate.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Every dupe answers the OP question. Just read their answers carefully till the ends.

Comment: @273K I did. I didn’t find the answer. If it’s there, link it directly please. Don’t play cat-and-mouse. — Please note that OP does *not* want to overload the function (as per their comment), so `using Base::test;` isn’t the answer (in case that’s what you were referring to).

Comment: @markzzz, why not to build code without `-Woverloaded-virtual`?

Comment: I agree with @ks1322 why not just drop the `-Woverloaded-virtual`? Also see [Hiding overloaded virtual function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851669/hiding-overloaded-virtual-function)

Comment: This warning is useful in general, so disable it locally with `#pragma`s, instead of globally with a flag. *"I do know that I'm doing stuff "correctly""* But why, though?

Comment: Add this to the end of Derived: `private: void test() override { Base::test(); }`

Comment: @Eljay It’s enough to add `private: using Base::test;` to get the same effect; that’s probably the best solution, but it still overloads the method (although only accessibly inside the class) which isn’t what OP seems to want.

Comment: *"how can I tell compiler that the called function is the overloaded one, correctly?"* -- The compiler already knows which function is being called. That's not what the warning is about. Nor is the function call triggering the warning; the warning is triggered by the `void test(int asd)` declaration. (You would get the same warning if you removed the line `derived.test(2);`.)

Comment: @JaMiT of course, but what the purpose of the warning so? Its like "select" the right overloaded function (picking the non virtual one).

Comment: @markzzz *"what the purpose of the warning so?"* -- As with most warnings, the purpose is to alert the programmer to something that is likely, but not definitely, an error. Don't think of "good" cases; think of mistakes people might make. In your `Base` class, change the declaration to `virtual void test(int& asd)`. Then look at your example and ask yourself how obvious is it that the ampersand was intentionally left off of the parameter's type in `Derived`? In this context, if someone did `int i = 1; Base* b = new Derived; b->test(i);` which function does that someone expect to be called?

Comment: @JaMiT clear, thanks.